# Python script to change dictionary content of another python script

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a Python script to create a 'mock ultrasound' machine. It runs on a Raspberry Pi, with a long USB cable at the end with an RFID reader.
The user 'scans' a mannequin with RFID chips under the skin. When it scans a chip, it displays a gif associated with the tag's string. That information is contained in 2 dictionaries. (one dictionary is 'pre-intervention' and the other is 'post intervention'. The script switches which dictionary is in use by pressing a button onscreen. The idea is that a medical learner finds a problem with their first scan, they do something to fix the problem, and then they check to see if it's been fixed.

I want to make a simple way to change which gif is associate with the tags. Something simple so my colleagues who do not know anything about coding could do on their own without me.

Either as a GUI form, or prompt for each dictionary entry (although that would not be preferable as there will eventually be a lot of dictionary entries).

Sorry if this isn't the right place.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import sys
import os

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

WINDOW_STYLE = '''
background-color:black; 
color:white;
'''


class Ui_Widget(QWidget):
    
    # You need to change this
    CARD_DICT = {
        # PIN:  IMAGE_PATH
        #### PRE INTERVENTION IMAGES ####
        #### Charlie ####
        #left appex
        '13603414011682': 'images/no-sliding.gif',
        #right appex
        '1360739520482': 'images/Normal-lung-sliding.gif',
        #heart
        '136010319878103': 'images/heart.gif',
        #mid clavicular
        '136073122213110': 'images/placeholder.gif',
        #sub xyphoid
        '136034217194177': 'images/subxiphoid.gif',
        #diaphragm
        '1360352372244': 'images/placeholder.gif',
        #supra umbilicus
        '1360739715155': 'images/placeholder.gif',
        #right lateral
        '136034163207198': 'images/NEGATIVE-FAST-LUQ.gif',
        #left lateral
        '1360738615152': 'images/NEGATIVE-FAST-LUQ.gif',
        # bladder
        '136072188183203': 'images/bladder.gif',
        
        #### Hagrid ####
        #top heart
        '13607295230121': 'images/---.gif',
        # left of the heart
        '13607311243154': 'images/---.gif',2
        
        #middle heart
        '13603452226124': 'images/---.gif',
        # sub xiphoid
        '136010456116172': 'images/---.gif',
        #mid clavicular
        '1360739618627': 'images/---.gif',
        # Right appex
        '136034130156180': 'images/---.gif',
        # left appex
        '136034163154147': 'images/---.gif',     
        # right lateral
        '1360721779716': 'images/---.gif',
        # left lateral
        '136035225193139': 'images/---.gif',
        # bladder
        '1360341692724': 'images/---.gif'
        
        
        
    }
    # Change this too
    ### POST INTERVENTION IMAGES ###
    CARD_DICT_2 = {
        # PIN:  IMAGE_PATH
        #### Charlie ####
        #left appex
        '13603414011682': 'images/Normal-lung-sliding.gif',
        #right appex
        '1360739520482': 'images/Normal-lung-sliding.gif',
        #heart
        '136010319878103': 'images/heart.gif',
        #mid clavicular
        '136073122213110': 'images/placeholder.gif',
        #sub xyphoid
        '136034217194177': 'images/subxiphoid.gif',
        #diaphragm
        '1360352372244': 'images/placeholder.gif',
        #supra umbilicus
        '1360739715155': 'images/placeholder.gif',
        #right lateral
        '136034163207198': 'images/NEGATIVE-FAST-LUQ.gif',
        #left lateral
        '1360738615152': 'images/NEGATIVE-FAST-LUQ.gif',
        # bladder
        '136072188183203': 'images/bladder.gif',
        
        
        #### Hagrid ####
        #top heart
        '13607295230121': 'images/---.gif',
        # left of the heart
        '13607311243154': 'images/---.gif',
        #middle heart
        '13603452226124': 'images/---.gif',
        # sub xiphoid
        '136010456116172': 'images/---.gif',
        #mid clavicular
        '1360739618627': 'images/---.gif',
        # Right appex
        '136034130156180': 'images/---.gif',
        # left appex
        '136034163154147': 'images/---.gif',     
        # right lateral
        '1360721779716': 'images/---.gif',
        # left lateral
        '136035225193139': 'images/---.gif',
        # bladder
        '1360341692724': 'images/---.gif',
        '136073148128213': 'images/placeholder.gif'
    }
    step = 1

    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_Widget, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Simulated Ultrasound')
        # Full screen
        self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
        # No close, minimize and miximaze window button
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet(WINDOW_STYLE)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Widget):
        Widget.setObjectName("Widget")
        Widget.resize(800, 600)

        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Widget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(780, 0))
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 10))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)

        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(
            40, 10, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum
        )
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Widget)

        self._widget = Widget
        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.reset) # type: ignore
        # Check every time the text line input changed
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.submit_pass) # type: ignore

    def retranslateUi(self, Widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate

        Widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("Widget", "Widget"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Widget", "Simulated Ultrasound"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Widget", "PIN Phrase"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Widget", "Type your PIN Phrase. Then press ENTER to submit"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Widget", "Reset"))
        selt.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color = black;")

    def submit_pass_str(self, input_str):
        """here the application accept user input"""
        if input_str in self.CARD_DICT:
            if self.step == 1:
                self.display_image(self.CARD_DICT[input_str])
            else:
                self.display_image(self.CARD_DICT_2[input_str])
            self.label_2.setText('')
        else:
            self.label_2.setText(f'Invalid: {input_str}')

    def display_image(self, path):
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
        if ext and ext.lower() == '.gif':
            movie = QMovie(path)
            self.label.setMovie(movie)
            movie.start()
        else:
            image = QPixmap(path)
            self.label.setPixmap(image)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(1, 1)

    def submit_pass(self):
        """Usage example using PIN Phrase input form"""
        self.submit_pass_str(self.lineEdit.text())

    def reset(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate

        if self.step == 1:
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Widget", "Close"))

        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self._widget.close) # type: ignore
        self.label.setText(_translate("Widget", "Simulated Ultrasound"))
        self.step += 1
        self.lineEdit.setFocus(True)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui_Widget()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What you should do is save the dictionaries in a json file and load the information into your application at runtime.  Then if modification need to be made its as simple as editiing a json file.  There are tons of GUIs that already do that and making one yourself is pretty simple also.

Comment: Oh that's a great start. I'll look into doing that. Thank you!